# Version Specific Tag Validation on Tag Synonym Page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-synonyms

Unless I'm completely mistaken about the concept of tag synonyms, I believe there is a bug in the validation logic on the tag synonyms page.

The Tag Synonym Page in Question: [Nine-Patch](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/nine-patch/synonyms)
Proposed Tag Synonym: [9Patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/9patch) (it's been used by 18 questions)
Error message when attempting to create it:

> Failed to propose synonym: 
>   Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators

Should a tag really be presumed to be a version tag if it is preceded by a single numeral?

I can understand why the following would be presumed to be version-specific tags:

- sql-server-2008
- .NET-2.0
- ruby-on-rails-3.1
- etc.

But those all use a numeric suffix, not prefix.  If this behavior is as designed, then perhaps a moderator could add 9patch as a synonym for nine-patch?

Comment: I set up the synonym, although the overall issue you're reporting remains.

Comment: @AnnaLear: I ran into the same issue when I tried to suggest unity-game-engine as a tag synonym for unity3d. unity3d has been chosen to distinguish the Unity game engine from MS Unity. Can you help? Thanks

Comment: @Kay I'm sorry, I don't quite follow what should be a synonym of what there or why. Can you make a new meta post with the details and an explanation please? Sorting this out in comments here isn't the best way to go. Thanks!

Comment: @AnnaLear see [Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157869/version-specific-synonyms-can-only-be-created-by-moderators)