# Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators

Tags: feature-request, support, tag-synonyms

I tried to suggest the existing tag unity-game-engine (6 questions) as a tag synonym for [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) (> 1000 questions). Although I have [create tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) privilege I run into the following error:

> Failed to propose synonym:
>
> Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators

It sounds to me like the 3d in unity3d is considered as version number. Actually it stands for 3-dimensional. Am I missing something? Maybe version specific tags should rather have a flag set, indicating their special status instead of being recognised by a regular expression only. Or at least the check should be restricted to the end of the tag's name e.g. `"[0-9]$"`.

There is a similar question 
[Version Specific Tag Validation on Tag Synonym Page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121457/version-specific-tag-validation-on-tag-synonym-page), I set up a new one as a moderator explicitly asked for it.

Comment: I added the synonym for you.

Comment: Same issue, http://stackoverflow.com/tags/agiletoolkit/synonyms needs synonym "atk4", could someone please add?

Comment: same issue, I would like to propose `lmer` as a synonym for `lme4`: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/lme4/synonyms

Comment: @RobertHarvey I got the same issue. Could you create the same synonym for `wifi` tag which is the same as `802.11` - not sure why I go the same error as Kay did when I tried to propose tag synonym in SO - thanks