# Are tags composed completely of numbers permitted?

Tags: support, tags

I just had to edit [400](/questions/tagged/400) out of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14046294/168868), clearly discussing HTTP status code 400 Bad Request, which uses [http-status-code-400](/questions/tagged/http-status-code-400).

I thought that tags composed only of numbers could not be created.  Was this is a recent change, or am I misremembering the block?

Comment: I've never heard of this rule myself. The only thing that comes to mind as far as numbers is only moderators can create version-specific tags or whatever that exact rule is. Although, I can't really think of any good examples where a number alone would make a good tag. So if this isn't a rule, it probably should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're misremembering.

Tags with numbers in them are sometimes interpreted as version tags, which [has some flaws](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157869/version-specific-synonyms-can-only-be-created-by-moderators), but other than that... if the tag itself is just a number because that's the concept it refers to, that seems fine to me.

Perhaps "http-400" might be a better choice in this case, but if I were asking question, I'd probably just search for the number "400" when typing in a tag anyway.

Comment: FWIW, there's a fleet of `html-status-code-FOO` tags.  Wasn't responsible for the naming, but they're not horrible.  I'll take verbosity over brevity when naming things...

Comment: There's already a [tag:http-status-code-400] tag, which is the second result that comes up when you do search for "400" in the tag suggestion box (minus the new [tag:400] tag).

Comment: @Charles Fair enough. The point remains - number-only tags aren't explicitly disallowed. Synonyms/merges can be set up if they're misused, though.